# Can't get my strong parameters nested correct in Ruby on Rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to add an array of objects (tasks in this case) as a return type in my controller for the root object (project). One project has many tasks and I'd like to save it all at once, but I keep getting the following error indicating that the return type isn't correct.

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Task(#47457277775360) expected, got {"name"=>"Some task", "start"=>"2019-12-05T03:38:48.555Z", "end"=>"2019-12-14T03:38:48.555Z"} which is an instance of ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#47457266882220))
```

The whitelisted parameters I have are like this

```
# whitelist params
params.permit(:name, :description, tasks: [:name, :start, :end])
```

The data being returned for the above example:

```
{"name"=>"asdf", "description"=>"zxvccxvzzxcvxcvcxvzxcvz", "tasks"=>[{"start"=>"2019-12-05T03:38:48.555Z", "end"=>"2019-12-14T03:38:48.555Z", "name"=>"Some task"}]}
```

[Edit] - Here are the models we're working with

```
# app/models/task.rb
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  # model association
  belongs_to :project

  # validation
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

```
# app/models/project.rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  # model association
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks

  # validations
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

Comment: Can you show the models for the task and other one witch stores name and description.

Comment: @PardeepSaini Sure thing, added in an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per rails documentation `Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent`. So in your strong params you need to pass attributes like this.

```
params.permit(:name, :description, task_attributes: [:name, :start, :end])
```

I suggest you to bind all params under one attribute like this

```
params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, task_attributes: [:name, :start, :end])
```

so you must send params from frontend like

```
{"project": {"name"=>"asdf", "description"=>"zxvccxvzzxcvxcvcxvzxcvz", "task_attributes"=>[{"start"=>"2019-12-05T03:38:48.555Z", "end"=>"2019-12-14T03:38:48.555Z", "name"=>"Some task"}]}}
```

You can read the documentation from https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I'm getting `Unpermitted parameters: :tasks` from your initial recommendation. I'll need to refactor some things to try out your recommendation, in the meantime, thank you!

Comment: Actually you are sending params in the wrong format from the frontend. You need to fix your form for sending params in correct format.